# Add "bloom" effect to object using Radeon ProRender

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, radeon-prorender-render-engine, glare

I'm following [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTu3Xssw67Q) but instead of rendering in Cycles, I'm using Radeon ProRender, because my laptop has Radeon graphics and it makes it easier.

On minute 7'53" of the tutorial, the instructor changes from Cycles renderer to EEVEE, so that they can activate the "Bloom" option of EEVEE, giving the object a nice glare.

Unfortunately, I've not been able to replicate the same effect using Radeon ProRender, and I cannot test the effect on EEVEE because I'm using the Radeon PR proprietary shader nodes (RPR nodes). So every time I switch to EEVEE the object renders black, maybe bc it doesn't recognize the RPR shaders. Can someone please help me get the same glare effect on Radeon ProRender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve answered most of your own question. However, to replicate the EEVEE Bloom effect regardless of render engine, hop into the compositor, check “Use Nodes” to turn it on, and use the Glare node between the render layer and the output.

Comment: And the glare is there! Thanks a lot!